# Get name of library for specific object vba

Tags: vba, reference

I have looked everywhere and coulndt find a way to do this:

I have created an object with late binding as such:

```
set objNtWork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
```

Now I want to add a reference in my project to the library.

How do I find the library name for that object?

Comment: Windows Script Host   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wscript

Comment: I found that page myself, but it does not help me. If I follow that page, then the reference I needed to set was "Windows Script Host". There is no such library. What I find is "Windows Script Host Object Model". But in that library there is no class WScript. So it is a dead end.

Comment: `Dim x As WshNetwork`  Pressing F2 will show the object explorer and you can see from there.

Comment: `Dim x as WshNetwork` resolves to an error. `Dim x As WScript.Network` resolves to an error as well. 

`Set objNtWork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")` does not add anything helpful to the objectbrowser neither. Thanks for the help, but I dont understand what you are getting at tbh...

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Alluding()

Dim o As Object

Set o = CreateObject("wscript.network")

Debug.Print TypeName(o)

End Sub
```

Returns

IWshNetwork2

So use as follows, Add the reference Windows Script Host Object Model:

```
Dim x As New WshNetwork

x.AddPrinterConnection "printername", "remotename"
```

So the following will show :

```
Sub Alluding()

Dim o As Object

Set o = CreateObject("wscript.network")

Debug.Print TypeName(o)


Dim w As New WshNetwork

Debug.Print TypeName(w)

End Sub
```

IWshNetwork2
IWshNetwork2

The same :)

Comment: I honestly dont know how this is related to the question...

The library name (like **Windows Script Host Object Model**) is what I want to find for the class `WScript.Network` (or any other class for that matter).

The library **Windows Script Host Object Model** does NOT contain the `WScript.Network` class. 

Neither do you allude as to how to find the library name from the class.

Comment: It contains "WshNetwork" as in "W" indows "S"cript "H"ost "Network"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the windows registry:

Search for "WScript.Network" in the registry editor:

[Registry Editor View 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPoiJ.png)

Then in the parent key, you will find the friendly name (Windows Script Host Network Object):
[Registry Editor View 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzq5I.png)

You can also find the location of the ocx file in the InProcServer32 key. You can use this with the browse option in Excel, for example, which will also give you the name of the reference.